# cs7069: Reference to type 'IAuthenticationProvider' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Graph.Core', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, graph

I have the following logic:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SharePointSearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set the API endpoint and scopes
            string graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            // Set the client ID and secret
            string clientId = "<your-client-id>";
            string clientSecret = "<your-client-secret>";

            // Create a new instance of the GraphServiceClient
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId("<your-tenant-id>")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

The error is on the last line after the new keyword.  This is what my project file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="7.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" Version="1.0.0-preview.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.12.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.12.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've been googling but I haven't found anything that really solves my issue just yet.  If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.